# Scene from Forbidden Planet where the monster kills Morbius

Tags: deleted-scenes, forbidden-planet

I have seen Forbidden Planet so many times, I have lost count. What has troubled me for years is I know for sure I saw it at least once, if not twice where when the monster from the ID burns through the shields, it grabs Morbius and shakes, then drops him, thus killing him. You can clearly see the reaction from Alta and the Commander, but they never show it. WHY? I guess it was considered too brutal so they cut it. Does anyone but me remember seeing that in the film?

Comment: Just to be clear are you saying there was a scene where you see Morbius get killed but it was cut and now the scene just cuts to the reactions?

Comment: For reference -- here is the relevant scene in the version not directly showing Morbius' death:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0aO1sSILNw

Comment: It's not one of the deleted scenes from the laserdisc at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dd-5qR5AD4 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu-gLQ4XyB0 and according to https://www.dvdtalk.com/dvdsavant/s30fplanmiss.html there is probably no such scene. Psychological research suggests all our memories are largely [reconstructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructive_memory) rather than snapshots, and it's very easy for suggestions or ideas to influence them, see the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xv-UAPbcbNU ...I'd guess your memory is based on what you inferred happened.

Comment: The scene Invisible Trihedron supplied in the link is all I've ever seen, and I, likewise, have seen _Forbidden Planet_ **many** times.  I suspect you're blending this scene with the ID monster crashing thru the fence into the camp.  Some picking up and shaking there.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a scan](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Forbidden-Planet.pdf) of an actual production script for *The Forbidden Planet*.  There is no indication of such a scene, with the ending playing out essentially as in the final version of the film.  Nor is there anything like this scene in the novelization of the film.  So you must be misremembering.

Having the monster kill Morbius would probably not, in any case, make much sense in the context of the film.  Since the id monster is made up of Morbius subconscious thoughts, it is acting according to his hidden desires—to keep himself and his daughter safe on the planet at any cost, certainly not to cause his own death.  The climactic defeat of the monster comes when Morbius, finally understanding what is happening and making a literally superhuman effort, renounces and dispels the monster; and moreover, it only works when he really wants his daughter to go free and for the ship’s crewmen to come to no further harm.  (See here:  [Causes of Morbius' death and the disappearance of the Id monster](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/184010/causes-of-morbius-death-and-the-disappearance-of-the-id-monster/184024#184024) for Morbius’s death scene from the novelization, told from his own point of view.)  A scene with Morbius being killed by the monster would ruin this.

Answer (score 0):

I watched this movie as a child.  The scene described where Morbius is lifted off the ground by the monster from the id, and killed by same is absolutely correct.  This part of the movie scared me very much as the time and I remember it precisely as described. In fact, I am relieved to know that my recollection is confirmed as I also could not find it on the DVD. I suspect it was deleted as too intense, which from experience is true.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please note that in order for an answer to be considered a good answer, it should include at least some supporting evidence. You haven't offered any such evidence here, you're just telling us that you remember the same scene, which proves nothing about whether that scene genuinely exists or not. It's entirely possible for two people to have the same false memory, especially if it pertains to something that was implied to have occurred off-screen, and therefore something multiple viewers might have pictured within their own minds, without ever having truly seen it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: My response clearly and unequivocally answers this question:  “Yes, I do remember.”   I was very happy to find this site where someone else INDEPENDENTLY raised the same issue.   An issue that has bothered me for some time.    Here are more details.  In the death scene, Morbius denies the monster from the id.  He approaches and reacts in horror.  In the DVD version, the scene shifts and he lies dying.  In my version, he approaches the monster.  He is lifted off the ground and killed.  The DVD then picks up his dying word.  This scene clarifies his death, but it was intense.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the original ending three times and no, no one is misremembering. The id monster enters the lab, picks up Morbius and tosses him—- just as in the attack on the ship. Morbius’sudden death scene then makes sense. However, that ending has been deleted. I haven’t yet found a restored version. My personal take is 1950s audiences found it too violent—-  and a lot of young children were seeing Forbidden Planet. This remains an incredible movie despite moments of fifties social mores. However, it bothers me every time I see the cut from Morbius screaming at the monster, to Adams & Altaira, back to Morbius now mysteriously collapsed and dying. It is not enough for Morbius to have a psychological break. The key climax scene is missing— the only way for the id to disappear, for the Krell machines to suddenly lose power, is for the monster to strike down the master. Remember, the mighty Krell disappeared mysteriously too and Morbius’ graphic death clarifies how they died. I feel fortunate to have seen the original version of this critical scene. It would not be considered violent at all to 21st century audiences.